# Why A-frame v 0.7.0 does not work with https?

Tags: aframe

when I redirect a site to from http to https, aframe starts to work wrong, like if everything is moving to different directions and this is only when in mobile is displayed,

Could somebody solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers now enforce HTTPS for sites to have access to the DeviceMotion and WebXR APIs. On top, users have to grant permission to enable them. Using A-Frame 1.0.4 or newer and serving your site HTTPS should get everything working as  expected. See [example](https://glitch.com/~aframe)